# How do I execute PHP on a cPanel server?

Tags: php, cpanel

I have a LAMP application that works. I can deploy this in 15 minutes on a Linux server. I was handed a VPS to deploy it. All I get is WHM. I created an account and that got me a login to cPanel and to the box. cPanel ran some wizard that told me to put my "web source files" in /public_html There is an /cgi-bin inside of that. I cannot get any web assets to be visible from any of those folders. All I get is 404 not found. chmod 777. 404 not found.

My simple question is this: how could I get a simple hello world PHP script to run on a cPanel server? I've been building web pages since before we called them web pages. I do not need to know anything about PHP itself I want to know how to get the cPanel managed server to run PHP scripts. All the documentation I can find on cPanel assumes you've been using it forever. I just need some basic information. Where do I put my PHP code ?????

Comment: you put it in the `public_html` folder.  Slap an index.php file in there and it should work.  You probably don't have your account setup correctly, do you have the domain name pointing to your `public_html` folder?  Is your domain dns settings pointing to the new server you just setup?

Comment: btw, that is usually the default setup...so 99% of the time people create a new client account in whm, deploy their code and database and it works.  You might not find a ton of help online about that because it is the most basic thing that is never a problem, that's just how it works.  My guess is you have some sort of "reseller" setup from your hosting provider and there are some funky configurations or environmental settings out of ordinary.  I'd ask them, only they will know what mess they're created.  cpanel can be customized by hosts...

Comment: i added an index.php file and it still goes to the default page that says Sorry server is misconfigured... I need to be able to access pages directly by name - not all pages are index.php. I do not have a domain name yet i'm just using the IP address of the server - same one WHM and cPanel are on. I set up this account as a normal account as far as I know. I know zero about resellers. I just want to host my client's website that's it.

Comment: so if i'm understanding things correctly - I did what i'm supposed to do it just isn't working - something is amuck with this server as I suspected? I'm going to delete this user and add another user and try this again. if I get the same thing the second time - which i'm quite certain I will (what's the definition of insanity?) then i'll complain to the company that sold my client the VPS. That's a LOT of money to pay for a server that doesn't let you do anything on it! Even if I get this working this WHM / cPanel stuff doesn't allow users to configure hardly anything at all. Very restrictive!

Comment: Is the lack of a domain the problem? My client does not have a domain for this server. I told him we could just use the IP-address to access web services (what i'm deploying now) on this server from apps and other web applications - nobody is going to access this from a web browser yet - so when I set up the client I made up a domain name that doesn't exist. If this is the problem I can fix it easily I hope - i can get a cheesy free domain name and point it to what? the IP-address of this server? nothing special? am I on to something here?

Comment: it's not that restrictive, like I said, your hosting provider probably has a lot of it "locked down" so you don't mess with it.  I think your issue is probably trying to access it via IP.  When you create the account in WHM, use an actual domain name in the domain name field.  Then on your local machine you can modify your hosts file to have that domain name point to the new server.  Then when your example.com request comes into the server, it will send you to the example.com account.  It doesn't know which account to send you to if you are trying via just the ip.

Comment: yeah, I think you figured it out now.  If it's just you testing, you can use any domain name you want and modify your hosts file.  If you want them to be able to test it out, buy a cheap one.  I keep a couple cheap ones just for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks! I figured this would be something that once someone figured it out it would seem rather obvious in retrospect. They're using Virtual Hosts to manage multiple sites on one virtual server so I have to use the domain name to access it. The fix was: I used a valid domain name when I set up a customer account in WHM - the domain name was not pointed at this server yet. on my local machine I added a line to my hosts file for that domain name pointing it to the IP-address of the server.

Answer (score 2):

This is the way cPanel works. If you host your website on shared IP address (main IP address of your server), you cannot access your website using IP address directly. You will always redirect to "http://IP/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi URL.

To access your website without pointing our domain to your server, you can use temporary URL. By default, it is enabled on the cPanel server. You can access the temporary URL using the following URL:

http://IP/~cpanel_user

Please note that the temporary URL does not work under the following configuration:

- If you have enabled mod_userdir tweak and didn't exclude default host
- If your server is configured to use mod_ruid2

Hope this information will help you with future use.